# AWS Serverless Express in local environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-serverless

I would like to use the [AWS Serverless Express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) in my local environment in order to use a Lambda function easily.

The `npm run local` doesn't start a web server but rather executes the Lambda function once with the `api-gateway-event.json` file.

Does anyone know some tools that allows local development with a web server that executes a Lambda function? 
Are there any best practices in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `app.local.js` script in the `basic-starter` example in the AWS Serverless Express project [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/master/examples/basic-starter/app.local.js).

#### app.local.js

This is a local version of the app file that contains:

```
const app = require('./app')
const port = 3000

app.listen(port)
console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
```

#### local command

You then run your local instance with the following command:

`node app.local.js`

#### deployments

For more information on working locally with AWS services and the deployment process around it, this article may help too: [Deploy a REST API using Serverless, Express and Node.js](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/)